# Show that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am given that $A$ is a square matrix and $B=C^{-1}AC.$ I'm trying to show that $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

So far I have said the following:

$$p_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$$

$$p_B(\lambda)= \det(B-\lambda I)=\det(C^{-1}AC-\lambda C^{-1}C)= \det(C^{-1}(A-\lambda I)C) $$

I feel like I'm pretty much there but I don't know how to finish it off. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: Note: One should write \det, not \text{ det }.  That automatically provides proper spacing in things like $a\det b$ and $a\det(b)$ (Notice that the former has more space to the right of $\det$ than the latter). $\qquad$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Last step (you were so close!): the determinant is multiplicative, so

$$\det\left(C^{-1}(A-\lambda I)C\right)=\color{red}{\left(\det C\right)^{-1}}\cdot\det(A-\lambda I)\cdot \color{red}{\det C}=\det(A-\lambda I)$$